# If-Else statement not functioning

Tags: objective-c, ios, if-statement, xml-parsing

I have a if-else statement which isn't quite working as I would want it to. This is the method before the statement which holds the variables:

```
[self.conditionsLabel setText:weather.weathercondition];
NSLog(@"%@", weather.weathercondition);
condition = weather.weathercondition;
```

Here is the if-else statement:

```
if ([weather.weathercondition isEqualToString:@"Clear"]) {
    conditionsImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sun.png"];
}
else {
    conditionsImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Partly_Sunny.png"];
}
```

In my console, the weather.weathercondition comes up as clear, but when it goes through the if-else statement, it always goes to the else and shows the Partly_Sunny.png. I'm testing it right now, and I know that the string is going to be "Clear". I am getting the data from an XML source and this is how it shows the data if I look at it on the internet :

```
<weatherDesc>
<![CDATA[ Clear ]]>
```

Is this the cause? It says the CDATA before Clear, but in the code, it always logs as Clear, without the CDATA and other things. I tried putting the `<![CDATA[ Clear ]]>` in the isEqualToString:, but the same results came. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to parsing XML and relatively new to Objective-C, so please excuse any errors (not in the code, but generally). I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: make sure there is not invisible character in your string

Comment: @Programmer2005: Just a friendly tip - when writing questions and answers, if you select your code and XML samples and press the "code" button when posting examples such as these (or if you indent them by four spaces), you won't have issues such as your angle brackets (`<` and `>`) being interpreted as markup. For short inline samples, use backticks (`). See [Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, sorry, I wasn't really sure how I was supposed to it, and it was my responsibity to check the editing help, thanks again for the tip. You learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDATA is a construct to denote that whatever inside should be treated as plain text (not XML). When XML parser detects it, it will remove the CDATA construct and present the data inside the construct.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I never saw it before so I was confused, but I understand now, thanks!

Comment: Turns out it took away the first space after CDATA, but not the space after the condition (in my example So my string was not "Clear" but it was "Clear "). Since the space was at the end of the string, I wasn't able to realize that it was there, but after some testing, I realized that it was causing the problem, and after that, it worked! The parser doesn't take the space after it, only before it(at least in my case).

Answer (score 0):

set instead of

```
[self.conditionsLabel setText:weather.weathercondition];
```

use this line

```
[self.conditionsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", weather.weathercondition]];
```

after that get your `weather.weathercondition`

get `NSString` and check with if statement

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
<weatherDesc>
<![CDATA[ Clear ]]>
```

to

```
<weatherDesc>
<![CDATA[Clear]]>
```

Comment: That's not controllable by me, and like nhahtdh said, it's "a construct to denote what're inside should be treated as plain text" so when the Parser detects it, all the invisible strings are taken away.